# DbConnectionStringBuilder does not parse when used in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use capabilities of `DbConnectionStringBuilder` for parsing connection-string-like user input. This works just fine in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sb = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        sb.ConnectionString = "server = 'smtp.gmail.com'; port = 587; user = you@gmail.com";
        Console.WriteLine(sb["server"]);
        Console.WriteLine(sb["port"]);
        Console.WriteLine(sb["user"]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
smtp.gmail.com
587
you@gmail.com
```

But it does not work in PowerShell. Namely, this literally translated code in PowerShell

```
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.ConnectionString = "server = 'smtp.gmail.com'; port = 587; user = you@gmail.com"
$sb["server"]
$sb["port"]
$sb["user"]
```

produces no output at all.

Any ideas why? How to make `DbConnectionStringBuilder` to work as a parser in PowerShell?

Comment: It has happened again. As soon as I post a question, I find an answer shortly. Questions do stimulate. I will post the answers (on why and a workaround) but let me keep the question opened for a while as a teaser and a good PowerShell exercise (unless anybody needs the answer immediately).

Comment: I submitted this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/674159/setters-are-not-called-on-properties-of-classes-that-implement-idictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder` implements `IDictionary`. Powershell has a shorthand for dictionaries using `.` that allows retrieval and assignment of key/value pairs as if the key was a property:

```
$dict = @{}
$dict["key1"] = 'value1'
$dict.key2 = 'value2'
```

You can see that it is storing the entire connection string as a key/value pair instead of on the `ConnectionString` property this way:

```
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.ConnectionString = "server = 'smtp.gmail.com'; port = 587; user = you@gmail.com"
$sb #formatted table of key/value pairs
```

The easiest way to get around this is to call the `set_`/`get_` methods generated for properties:

```
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.set_ConnectionString("server = 'smtp.gmail.com'; port = 587; user = you@gmail.com")
$sb["server"]
$sb["port"]
$sb["user"]
```

Comment: Excellent. The `set_ConnectionString()` trick is new to me and it definitely looks simpler than the way proposed in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I remembered that `get_`/`set_` methods get generated for properties and those are what are actually called in IL. C# won't let you call them directly, but Powershell is more loosey-goosey so I took a shot and learned something new. But I also learned something from yours, that `PSObject` is the key to basic reflection in Powershell.

Answer (score 6):

It is probably a bug (a gotcha anyway) and I will submit it soon. It looks like PowerShell does not call setters on properties of classes that implement `IDictionary` (as `DbConnectionStringBuilder` does, and it is the setter of `ConnectionString` that parses the string).

Here are two demos (the original and workaround):

```
# test 1 - does not work, presumably PowerShell invokes $sb["ConnectionString"] = .. instead of the setter
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.ConnectionString = "server = 'smtp.gmail.com'; port = 587; user = you@gmail.com"

# the original string
$sb.ConnectionString

# nothing at all
$sb["server"]
$sb["port"]
$sb["user"]

# test 2 - works fine, we make PowerShell to invoke the ConnectionString property setter in this way
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.PSObject.Properties['ConnectionString'].Value = "server = 'smtp.gmail.com'; port = 587; user = you@gmail.com"

# parsed and re-formatted string
$sb.ConnectionString

# parsed data
$sb["server"]
$sb["port"]
$sb["user"]
```

Output:

```
server = 'smtp.gmail.com'; port = 587; user = you@gmail.com
server=smtp.gmail.com;port=587;user=you@gmail.com
smtp.gmail.com
587
you@gmail.com
```

As far as the workaround is found we get for free a pretty powerful parser  for connection-string-like data. Here is the demo that shows parsing of quite convoluted input:

```
# get the parser
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder

# input the string to parse using this workaround way
$sb.PSObject.Properties['ConnectionString'].Value = @'
Apostrophes = "Some 'value'";
Quotations = 'Some "value"';
Semicolons = '1; 2; 3';
Multiline = Line1
Line2
Line3;
Name with spaces = Some value;
Name with == sign = Some value;
'@

# get the parsed results

# the string: not the original but parsed and re-formatted
$sb.ConnectionString

# the data: parsed key/values
$sb | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Output:

```
apostrophes="Some 'value'";quotations='Some "value"';semicolons="1; 2; 3";multiline="Line1
Line2
Line3";name with spaces="Some value";name with == sign="Some value"

Key              Value              
---              -----              
apostrophes      Some 'value'       
quotations       Some "value"       
semicolons       1; 2; 3            
multiline        Line1              
                 Line2              
                 Line3              
name with spaces Some value         
name with = sign Some value
```

Comment: Was this ever formally submitted as a bug [is there a link]? And also has it been addressed in the past 6+ years (if so, as of which version)...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.Add("server","smtp.gmail.com")
$sb.Add("port",587)
$sb.Add("user","you@gmail.com")

$sb["server"]
$sb["port"]
$sb["user"]
```

Comment: I do not have the data you pass in `Add()`. That's the point of the question: the task is to extract that data from an input connection-string-like string.

Comment: ah, not sure on that one--it seems like it should work the same, but as you point out it doesn't. You could hack around it convertfrom-stringdata $($sb.ConnectionString -split ";" -join "`n")

Comment: :) How about complex strings like this: `apostrophes = "'foo'"; quotations = '"bar"'; semicolons = '1;2;3'; simple value = some value`? `DbConnectionStringBuilder` is the powerful parser, we should get its power for free.

Comment: Ageed I look forward to seeing your answer.