# Powershell regex for connectionStrings?

Tags: regex, string, parsing, powershell, connection

For some reason I'm having a brutal time parsing the connection string in the web.config file.

I've already gotten connectionString but I'm trying to get all the values such as the

- Data Source
- Initial Catalog
- Username
- etc...

The connection string looks like:

> Data Source=db.sample.com;user
>   id=sample-user;password=sample-password;Initial
>   Catalog=sample-catalog;

Comment: Do you need to use a regex? It looks like two calls to whatever Powershell uses for splitting strings would do the trick. One call to split on `;`, then loop through the results and split by `=` to get your key/value pairs. I'd put this as an answer but I don't know a) if Powershell has a split function, and b) what it's called.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder`

```
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder

# Attempting to set the ConnectionString property directly won't work, see below
$sb.set_ConnectionString('Data Source=db.sample.com;user id=sample-user;password=sample-password;Initial Catalog=sample-catalog;')

$sb
```

Output:

```
Key             Value          
---             -----          
data source     db.sample.com  
user id         sample-user    
password        sample-password
initial catalog sample-catalog
```

See also for more details: [DbConnectionStringBuilder does not parse when used in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6237708/323582)

(That is why this funny syntax `$sb.set_ConnectionString(...)` is used instead of `$sb.ConnectionString = ...`).

Comment: Thanks for this! Using .Net DbConnectionStringBuilder in a PowerShell script is really the best option of getting parts extracted the right way.