# How to update a connection string of an excel file from a script (PS)

Tags: excel, powershell, connection-string

We have an excel file which contains a connection to a database to retreive data (with a select statement).

We want to update via a (preferrably powershell) script the connection string of that file to make it query another server instead.

So for exemple : 
    I have report.xlsx file which connects to server A.
    I run update-connection.ps1
    And when I open report.xlsx it now connects to server B.

Any idea how we could do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an ODBC (system DNS) for the connection?

Comment: I have this in my connection string : Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; does that answer your question ? (and the file is computer-independant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly easy if you decide (are allowed) to store the connection (server name) in a worksheet. Your VBA code can dynamically build the connection string based on the value of a cell. (I would probably create a named range and use it in the code).

I don't know PowerShell but the code can look something like:

```
$workbook.Range("Server").Value2 = "PROD_01"
```

You can make the worksheet hidden if you wish, but it is not a serious security.

Comment: Sounds like the best idea so far, I think I'll try that.

Comment: Mixing this solution with the closed xml project suggested before might bring me where I want, although I had hoped for an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try automating Excel via PowerShell, as in this article: http://kentfinkle.com/PowershellAndExcel.aspx

If you don't want to automate Excel then you could try using something like ClosedXML in your PowerShell script: http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: that's a good start! After browsing a little bit their code, I'm not sure it's gonna work though...

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the connectionstring with System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder. Check this SO thread:

[Powershell regex for connectionStrings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614500/powershell-regex-for-connectionstrings)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I don't see in these threads how to update the connection string of the xlsx file.

Comment: It would be easier if you could post the code you are using to read the value.

Comment: That's my issue: I don't read nor write the value yet. I'll provide more info in my question.